# Get a Value from a SqlDataSource object's SelectCommand, then use the value in an If Statement

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, ms-access

So I need to get the value from from the Query - in the AS TrueOrFalse field.
I'm confused on how I should go about doing that.

In basic thought/wording: I need to see if there exists a value in BookID (that will match the RequestQuery) and then a value exists in the UserID (that matches/comes from the Session Variable) From my RatingsReviews Table.

I don't have access to the .ExecuteScalar Method.

I know the query *should* work, it works in Access (with slight modifications to use the parameter values) and, I am using the "BookID" RequestQuery and the "UserID" Session Variable for other things that work as intended.

This is what is in my WebPageName.aspx.cs file:

```
  SqlDataSource objDS2 = new SqlDataSource();

    objDS2.ProviderName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ProviderName;
    objDS2.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    //Puts  the Amount of times that the Session User ID (who's logged in) appears with the Requested Query String of the Book ID
    objDS2.SelectCommand = "SELECT COUNT (*) AS TrueOrFalse FROM [RatingsReviews] WHERE ([UserID]" + Session["UserID"].ToString() + " AND [BookID] =" + Request.QueryString["id"].ToString() + ")";

    //Get Value from the TrueOrFalse Field from the QUERY somehow


    //IF the The value in TrueOrFalse Field is 0, 
     // then allow and show the Panel, else hide panel - so they cannot enter a review

     // if (TrueOrFalse == 0/false) 
    // { 

          //is someone logged in?
        if (Session["UserID"] != null)
        {
          //if someone is logged in, and they are visiting
            if (Session["UserID"].ToString().Equals(Request.QueryString["id"]))
            {
            PanelUserRating.Visible = true;
            }
    else
       {
         PanelUserRating.Visible = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you only populate the SelectCommand property by you never executed the select command. You can use Select method to execute it and get the result back.

```
IEnumerable result = _objDS2.Select(new DataSourceSelectArguments());
```

Follow this link for proper implementation:
[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.select?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_UI_WebControls_SqlDataSource_Select_System_Web_UI_DataSourceSelectArguments)